# Getting error kendo undefined

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var attachmentTemplate = kendo.template($("#attachment").html());

function showAttachments(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
    var wnd = $("#Attachments").data("kendoWindow");

    wnd.content(attachmentTemplate(dataItem));
    wnd.center().open();
}
```

here am getting kendo undefined in kendo.template line even i have @kendo.mvc.ui

```
  columns.Command(command => command.Custom("Attachments").Click("showAttachments")).Title("Attachments");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Right click your all kendo references
- Set true to LocalCopy field
- Then clean project and build project

if other kendo elements works , this not work :)

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function showAttachments(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var attachmentTemplate = kendo.template($("#attachment").html());

    var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
    var wnd = $("#Attachments").data("kendoWindow");

    wnd.content(attachmentTemplate(dataItem));
    wnd.center().open();
}
```

try to take `var attachmentTemplate = kendo.template($("#attachment").html());` inside of the function

Comment: By default localcopy has set to true

Comment: try to set true 'kendo.web.min.js'  'copy to output directory' field

Comment: Sorry i went for lunch ...0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'kendo' is undefined and on button click attachments am getting  JavaScript runtime error: Object expected

Comment: var attachmentTemplate = kendo.template($("#attachment").html()); at this line am geting JavaScript runtime error: 'kendo' is undefined

Comment: here is what i am using http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/grid/custom-command.html?utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=twitter

Comment: I edited to my solution try like this just a hope :)

Comment: Did you have attachment template? Did you create it ?

Comment: <script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="attachment">
    <tr>
    <td>
    FileName:
    </td>
    </tr>
</script> can i have label like this